# Could I add wavy underline on VSCode editor?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

How to add wavy under line on a document by VSCode API like ESLint extension?
(and what should I call this line?)

[image]

I'm making a VSCode Extension.
And want to find the way to show comment on a document.

I guess that a way to do this is showing wavy under line and texts like ESLint.
But tell me if there is another better way.

Comment: create a `DiagnosticsProvider`

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I could know the word "Diagnostics" now. great hint.